# Problem when using ajax for refresh my own captcha with refresh button

Tags: jquery, ajax

But it doesn't work, I just get my image be vanished and I try METHOD 2,
I think it can work but I'm wrong coz i just get display with code of image not new captcha image 
I am stack and confuse about what method exactly work to refresh my own captcha..

Any wrong in my code or my method can't be used to refresh captcha..
Could anyone tell me how to refresh captcha exactly ?

Thanks in Advance

#### JQUERY CODE

```
$('.refresh_captcha').click( function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'captcha_mk.php',    
      success: function(data){
        //$('img').attr('src', data);  // METHOD 1 ( I try it and my image is lost )
        $('div').html('<img src=' + data); // METHOD 2 ( display code of image not captcha image)

    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because `captcha_mk.php` is returning the actual image data - remember that the `src` attribute takes an URL to the image file, not the actual image data. Therefore what you need would probably look like this:

```
$('.refresh_captcha').click(function(){
    $('img').attr('src', 'captcha_mk.php?cache=' + new Date().getTime());
});
```

We append a query string to the end of the URL to prevent browser caching.

Comment: thanks Yi it works... I can refresh my captcha and session keep update.

Comment: i want to ask about end of string in value of src, date() and getTime it's javascript function right?

Comment: @Joko Yes, the `getTime` function in `Date` objects give you the time stored in the object in Unix Epoch format.

Comment: @Yi: nice answer, function get time currently and added to value of src.. yihiyohoyaha

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what Captcha library you are using but try to find out what `data` holds. also have a class or ID for the captcha image and do:

```
$('img.myCaptcha').attr('src', data);
```

Read how you reload the [securimage](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart/) captcha library (step 4) just to understand the concept.

P.S: don't forget to `return false;` before closing the `click` function to prevent default behavior.

Comment: I use simple code to make captcha ( my own captcha ) not recaptcha